# Loop through an array to unset a known value and implode to sql

Tags: mysql, arrays, loops, foreach, implode

I have two set of arrays in different MYSQL table. This what I want to do

```
               What I Want TO Do
   TABLE_ONE            connect to the table.
                        get the value we want from session_id
                        THEN get the array associated with the value (session_id)
                        explode the array to get individual values.
                        NOW::::: - GO TO TABLE_TWO

   TABLE_TWO            Go straight to the first value from array (TABLE_ONE)
                        Explode the array associated with it.
                        Delete the number that's equal to the session_id
                       _____________________________________________________
                       And so fort....
```

More visual explanation below:
`session_id = 4`

TABLE_ONE:

```
   id            array1
   1             4
   2             1
   3             2,5
   4             1,3,4,5
   5             4,5
```

TABLE_TWO:

```
   id            array2
   1             4,6,9,2
   2             3,7,8,2
   3             7,12,4,9
   4             1,5,4,8
   5             3,6,12,3,5,4
```

So, because `session_id = 4`, we go to TABLE_ONE `id 4`. The array of id-4 is 1,3,4,5.
So now we know 4 can be found in `id 1,3,4,5 of TABLE_TWO`
We should now explode TABLE_TWO's array and delete `4` from there array. Implode the array and save the new value to database.

THIS IS WHAT I HAVE DONE - it would delete only '4' from them id-3 and delete all the values in id-4. Please help!!

```
    $SESSION = 4;
    $depSQL = mysql_query("SELECT array1 FROM TABLE_ONE WHERE id='$SESSION' LIMIT 1"); 
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($depSQL)) { $depARRAY = $row["array1"]; }
$explodedDEP = explode(",", $depARRAY);
foreach ($explodedDEP as $key1 => $value1) {

    $stSQL = mysql_query("SELECT array2 FROM TABLE_TWO WHERE id='$value1'"); 
    while($get=mysql_fetch_array($stSQL)) { $stARRAY = $get["array2"];}
    $explodedST = explode(",", $stARRAY);
        foreach ($explodedST as $key2 => $value2) {
              if ($value2 == $SESSION) {
                      unset($explodedST[$key2]);
              }
        }
         $newST = implode(",", $explodedST);
     $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE TABLE_TWO SET array2 ='$newST' WHERE id='$value2'");

}
exit();
```

Please help!!! I'm really struggling on it.
I have tried it for hours now and i havent really got any where.
I think the problem is with the inserting to database.
Please help.

Comment: `$SESSION = 4` should be `$SESSION['id'] = 4;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid one loop by using the array1 in your second SQL directly since it is already a comma seperated list.

Try this:
**EDIT:** Updated the code after testing.

```
    $SESSION['ID'] = 4;

$depSQL = mysql_query("SELECT array1 FROM TABLE1 WHERE id='".$SESSION['ID']."' LIMIT 1"); 

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($depSQL)) 
{ 
    $depARRAY = $row["array1"]; 
}
$stSQL = mysql_query("SELECT id, array2 FROM TABLE2 WHERE id IN ($depARRAY)") or die("Query Error"); 
while($get=mysql_fetch_array($stSQL)) { 
    $stARRAY = $get["array2"];
         $id =  $get["id"];
    $explodedST = explode(",", $stARRAY);
    foreach ($explodedST as $key2 => $value2) {
            if ($value2 == $SESSION['ID']) {
                            unset($explodedST[$key2]);
            }
    }
    $newST = implode(",", $explodedST);
    echo $id . " " . $newST . "<BR/>" ;
    $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE TABLE2 SET array2 ='$newST' WHERE id='$id'");
}
exit();
```

Comment: Hi Cybernate, It only deletes the number 4 from id-3(TABLE_TWO) and deletes all the values in id-4(TABLE_TWO). I don't know why it does that... Do you have any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Edited the post a minute back..didn't realize the update was using $value2. Please try with the new post...

Comment: Hi Cybernate, it doesn't still work. I tried to echo the key before and after the `unset($explodedST[$key2]);` code and it doesn't. It doesn't update the database aswel. Please help :(

Comment: I can't be lazy anymore :). Tried the code with dummy data and made one more correction. Tested it and it is working. Please try the updated post.

Comment: OKAY CYBERNATE - I OFFICALLY LOVE YOU.. :) --- YOU RULE!!!!! THANK YOU A BILLION TIMES!!! I HAVE BEEN ON THIS FOR HOURS!!! JUST A SMALL MISTAKE LOL. I LOVE YOU DUDE!!!

Comment: Hey Cybernate, I altered the code a bit and when I ran it, i got this error `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IN (233,1,2,3,265,6,7,8,9,)' at line 1` Do you know why that is? I checked and re-checked the code and there is nothing wrong with it. I even copied your code and changed the values, but no luck.

Comment: Were you able to fix it? I think the issue is with the comma at the end of the list in IN clause. Try replacing $depARRAY = $row["array1"] with $depARRAY = rtrim($row["array1"], ',')

Answer (score 1):

`$SESSION` is an array you can not assign value like this `$SESSION = 4;`

assign value like this

```
$SESSION['id'] = 4;
if ($value2 == $SESSION['id']) {
```

Comment: Hi Shakti, the above values are just to show you what I mean. Thank you for pointing that out. It works but it only deletes number '4' in id-3 (TABLE_TWO) and deletes all the values in id-4 (TABLE_TWO). Could you please have a look and point me to the right direction.